# How to recover QNetworkAccessManager

Tags: qt, qnetworkaccessmanager

I have an application and unplug my network cable: `QNetworkAccessManager` is not accessible. Now I plugin the network cable. But `QNetworkAccessManager` stays `Not accessible`.

In can set it like here:

`m_accessManager->setNetworkAccessible(QNetworkAccessManager::Accessible);`

But it does not really help. Requests from that QAM always fail (actually I never receive a response).

How can I recover such a QAM?

--

Related:

1. [Method to reset the QNetworkAccessManager backend](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11587827/356726)
2. [Alternative for QNetworkAccessManager](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14827212/356726)

Comment: `QNetworkAccessManager` implementation is very different across platforms. I usually use `QScopedPointer<QNetworkAccessManager> m_nm` and do `m_nm.reset(new QNetworkAccessManager)` for similar cases on Linux.

Comment: I have realized in the meantime that `NetworkAccessibility / UnknownAccessibility` takes a while to become `Accessible` in such cases. I receive the signal that `NetworkAccessibility` is `Accessible`, but `getNetworkAccessiblity` still returns unknown.

Answer (score 1):

What helped in my case is always recreating an instance of `QNetworkAccessManager`.